# How to query MongoDB multiple digit subcollection with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a multi-digit category table and I want to query the bottom category from that table.

This way I can get the first digit when I query, but it does not bring the lower digits

```
var query = Query<Category>.ElemMatch(x => x.SubCategories, builder => builder.EQ(actor => actor.IntegrationCategoryCode, categoryId));
var repository = new Data.MongoDB.Repository.MongoRepository<Category>();
var result= repository.CustomQuery(query).ToList();

[CollectionName("Category ")]
public class Category : Base.Entity
{
    [BsonElement("CategoryId")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("IntegrationCategoryName")]
    public string IntegrationCategoryName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("IntegrationCategoryCode")]
    public string IntegrationCategoryCode { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("IntegrationParentCode")]
    public string IntegrationParentCode { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Deleted")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Boolean)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("CreateDate")]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("UpdateDate")]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

    public List<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you convert this to IQueryable using C# mongo db driver and use LastorDefault method to get last item?

Comment: I try but result null.

Comment: can you share code you tried? Something like this should work. Collection.AsQueryable().where(x => x.SubCategories.select(sub=>sub.Actors).FirstOrDefault(xx=>IntegrationCategoryCode==CategoryId))

Comment: var result = repository.LastOrDefault(x => x.SubCategories.Any(a=> a.IntegrationCategoryCode == categoryId));

Comment: first you have to filter repository with matching category id and then you should apply last or default. This way it will return all in repository if .any condition evaluates to true other wise null if it returns false.

Comment: My collection {
    "IntegrationCategoryCode" : "1010",
    "SubCategories" : [ 
        { "IntegrationCategoryCode":"1011",
            "IntegrationParentCode":"1010",
        },
        {"IntegrationCategoryCode":"1051",
            "IntegrationParentCode":"1010",
            "SubCategories" : [ 
                {"IntegrationCategoryCode":"1782",
                    "IntegrationParentCode":"1051",
                }, 
                {"IntegrationCategoryCode" :"1783",
                    "IntegrationParentCode" :"1051",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I want to find "IntegrationCategoryCode" :"1783"

Comment: Ohh I see, you are referencing Category entity again, which will make it difficult to write query. May be you can trying searching how to implement self join in linq that might give you some clue on how to proceed with it, With no-sql database it looks very difficult.